# Create a calculation based on previous date and specific identifier

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an excel table that has a list of measurements and dates those measurements were taken. Each measurement is from a specific location. I need to perform a series of calculations that are based on the previous date. In the attached, the columns I need help with are in bold:

**Amt_Used**: Amount in date "x" from location "a" - amount in preceding date from location "a"

**Time_Diff**: Number of days between date "x" and preceding date.

Per_Day_Use: Amt_Used / Time_Diff

Remaining_Days: Amount from date "x" / Per_Day_Use

Date_Empty: Date "x" + remaining days

[Image of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEQAi.png)

Comment: Please share the Formula you have tried so far, help us to understand the issue!!

Comment: It sounds like you have three fields that we can call Value, Date, and Location. For a given row, you want to find the most recent previous date from the same location and then do math on those values. Can we assume the data is in order by date? (I.E., do we need to find the most recent data or can we just find the last row above the current row?) If the dates are in order, take a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/q/781992/348859) to find the last instance of a value in a column.

Comment: Could you send a sample here?